# How to adjust the components for screens of different sizes (Responsive Layout)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a login screen that I tested on different devices and found that the components do not fit on any screen. Could someone explain to me how I can create adpative screens

```
    <StackLayout Margin="20" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
        <!--<Image x:Name="PicLogo"  WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100" Aspect="AspectFit" VerticalOptions="Center" />-->
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="30">

            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image x:Name="PicUser"   WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30" Aspect="AspectFit"  VerticalOptions="Center"  />
                <local:RoundedEntry x:Name="txtUsuario" PlaceholderColor="Gray" Placeholder="ID do utilizador..." WidthRequest="220" ></local:RoundedEntry >
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                <Image x:Name="PicPass"  WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30" Aspect="AspectFit"  VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                <local:RoundedEntry x:Name="txtSenha"  PlaceholderColor="Gray" Placeholder="Palavra Passe..." IsPassword="True" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" WidthRequest="220"></local:RoundedEntry>

            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                <Label x:Name="LbEsquecer" Text="Esqueceu a palavra-Passe?" TextColor="White" />
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout x:Name="StkBotao" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                <Button x:Name="CmdLogin"  Text="Iniciar Sessão" BackgroundColor="#00a1e3" TextColor="White" FontSize="13.8"  HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" WidthRequest="200"></Button>
            </StackLayout>
            <!--<Button x:Name="CmdHelp"  Text="..." BackgroundColor="#00a1e3" HeightRequest="50" TextColor="White" BorderRadius="10" WidthRequest="40" HorizontalOptions="End"></Button>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button x:Name="CmdA"  Text="FAQs" BackgroundColor="LightGray"  BorderRadius="8"></Button>
                <Button x:Name="CmdB"  Text="Chat" BackgroundColor="LightGray"  BorderRadius="8"></Button>
                <Button x:Name="CmdC"  Text="Ajuda" BackgroundColor="Yellow"  BorderRadius="8"></Button>
            </StackLayout>-->
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: You have WidthRequest all over controls. This forces that control to be certain sizes without taking screen resolution into consideration. Same as HeightRequest.

Comment: Should I do the same for the rest of the screens? I have a maximum of 8 screens and they are not all responsive. I just do not know if I should touch the code behind and if I go there I will have a lot of difficulty due to lack of experience. @Woj

Comment: Try to avoid Height and Width Requests whenever you can. You probably want to ideally remove it from rest of the pages as well. Have a look at the Grid and how use it with your controls. Grids are great for screens with different resolutions.

Answer (score 1):

You basically needs to play with the following properties for each layout:

- HorizontalOptions
- VerticalOptions

For example, your parent StackLayout should have this properties set to `FillAndExpand` so it covers the whole screen on height and width. The immediately child should be vertically centered and also horizontally filled. Like so:

```
<!-- Parent stacklayout starts -->
<StackLayout
     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
     VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
     <!-- Immediately child stacklayout starts -->
      <StackLayout
          HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
          VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
          <!-- Your login markup starts -->

          <!-- Your login markup ends -->
      </StackLayout>
      <!-- Immediately child stacklayout ends -->
</StackLayout>
```

And the rest of childs falls into this base layout. Remember you are on a stacklayout where elements are placed in a stack manner.

Also don't forget to use HorizontalTextAlignment to actually align the elements under your stacklayouts, like so:

```
<!-- Parent stacklayout starts -->
<StackLayout
     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
     VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
     <!-- Immediately child stacklayout starts -->
      <StackLayout
          HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
          VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
          <!-- Your login markup starts -->
          <Label Text="Hi there!" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
          <Label Text="Here you have some tips" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
          <!-- Your login markup ends -->
      </StackLayout>
      <!-- Immediately child stacklayout ends -->
 </StackLayout>
```

Comment: Should I do the same for the rest of the other screens, making the layouts responsive? @Daniel Uribe ayvar

Comment: This is only an approach, you should be aware of each screen purpose because this may not be the best approach for a ScrollView or AbsoluteLayout.

Answer (score -1):

Example add views templates.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentView
    x:Class="MyAp.Views.MyNewView"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views">


    <ContentView.Content>
        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="View">
            <OnIdiom.Desktop>
                <views:NewView_Desktop />
            </OnIdiom.Desktop>
            <OnIdiom.Tablet>
                <views:NewView_Tablet />
            </OnIdiom.Tablet>
            <OnIdiom.Phone>
                <views:NewView_Phone />
            </OnIdiom.Phone>
        </OnIdiom>
    </ContentView.Content>
```

**Reference view, that will be independent.**

```
xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views

<views:MyFirstView />

<views:MySecondView />
```